# Tkinter canvas not updating the loops

Tags: python, tkinter-canvas

I want to make a program where a square goes from one side to another (in canvas) infinitely, but my program isn’t updating what is inside of the loops. I’m new to tkinter so sorry if this is some stupid mistake.
First, I had the mainloop at the end, but than it never got executed so the root was never displayed on the screen. I changed the program to this version, but now it’s like it stops executing at the point of mainloop: the loops don’t get executed and the square doesn’t move at all.
This is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x400")
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=600, height=400)
canvas.pack()
x = 300
y = 200
square = canvas.create_rectangle(x-10, y-10, x+10, y+10, fill="black")
root.mainloop()
for i in range(29):
    canvas.move(square, 10, 0)

while True:
    for j in range(58):
        canvas.move(square, -10, 0)
    for j in range(58):
        canvas.move(square, 10, 0)
```

Comment: The issue with your code is that the mainloop() function of the Tkinter window is blocking, meaning it will keep the program running and handle events (like mouse clicks or key presses), but it won't allow the execution of any code after it.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution. It uses `tk.Tk.after()` method to do timing interval tasks.

```py
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("600x400")
        canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=600, height=400)
        canvas.pack()
        x = 300
        y = 200
        square = canvas.create_rectangle(x-10, y-10, x+10, y+10, fill="black")
        for i in range(29):
            canvas.move(square, 10, 0)

        self.canvas = canvas
        self.square = square
        self.direction = -1 # -1 = left | 1 = right
        self.i = 0

    def mainloop(self, n: int = 0):
        self.update_square()
        super().mainloop(n)

    def update_square(self):
        if self.i < 58:
            self.i += 1
        else:
            self.i = 0
            self.direction *= -1
        self.canvas.move(self.square, 10 * self.direction, 0)
        self.after(100, self.update_square)

App().mainloop()
```